# After TFS upgrade, title field expects an "identity"

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem, workitem

I have upgraded from tfs 2013 update 3 to tfs 2015 update 2. I have two project collections, one that works fine. The other collection is causing me huge headaches!

I have team projects using custom templates but also scrum / agile and all team projects have the same problem within the problematic collection.

When I upgraded my old version of tfs (tfs 2013 update 3) It all looked fine, however within the collection team projects the work item “Title” fields were all “00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000”. I looked more into the problem and it looks like the system.title field is looking for an “Identity”.

When creating a new Product Backup log Item I enter “test” into the “Title” field, I get the following error “The identity for value “TEST” for field “TITLE” is an unknown identity”. The previous version of TFS (2013 update 3) the collection was attached too was working perfectly with no issues on the web front end.
We have exported the XML work item definitions, none of the “Title” fields have any constraints linking to a list of users, or any list for that matter – the only constraint is that the field is mandatory.

Has anyone had this issue or could give any indication what has happened? The only change from the old to the new environment is the old environment had a SharePoint server.

Just to confirm all work items contain the value “00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.

[image: Identity error - Backlog Item]

[image: System.Title After Upgrade]

[Product Backlog Item system.title example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20mcF.png)

[pbi.layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRimO.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<witd:WITD xmlns:witd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/typedef" version="1.0" application="Work item type editor">


-<WORKITEMTYPE name="Product Backlog Item">

<DESCRIPTION>Tracks an activity the user will be able to perform with the product.</DESCRIPTION>


-<FIELDS>

<FIELD name="Iteration Path" reportable="dimension" type="TreePath" refname="System.IterationPath"/>

<FIELD name="Iteration ID" type="Integer" refname="System.IterationId"/>

<FIELD name="External Link Count" type="Integer" refname="System.ExternalLinkCount"/>

<FIELD name="Team Project" reportable="dimension" type="String" refname="System.TeamProject"/>

<FIELD name="Hyperlink Count" type="Integer" refname="System.HyperLinkCount"/>

<FIELD name="Attached File Count" type="Integer" refname="System.AttachedFileCount"/>

<FIELD name="Node Name" type="String" refname="System.NodeName"/>

<FIELD name="Area Path" reportable="dimension" type="TreePath" refname="System.AreaPath"/>

<FIELD name="Revised Date" reportable="detail" type="DateTime" refname="System.RevisedDate"/>

<FIELD name="Changed Date" reportable="dimension" type="DateTime" refname="System.ChangedDate"/>

<FIELD name="ID" reportable="dimension" type="Integer" refname="System.Id"/>

<FIELD name="Area ID" type="Integer" refname="System.AreaId"/>

<FIELD name="Authorized As" type="String" refname="System.AuthorizedAs" syncnamechanges="true"/>


-<FIELD name="Title" reportable="dimension" type="String" refname="System.Title">

<REQUIRED/>

</FIELD>

<FIELD name="State" reportable="dimension" type="String" refname="System.State"/>

<FIELD name="Authorized Date" type="DateTime" refname="System.AuthorizedDate"/>

<FIELD name="Watermark" type="Integer" refname="System.Watermark"/>

<FIELD name="Rev" reportable="dimension" type="Integer" refname="System.Rev"/>

<FIELD name="Changed By" reportable="dimension" type="String" refname="System.ChangedBy" syncnamechanges="true"/>

<FIELD name="Reason" reportable="dimension" type="String" refname="System.Reason"/>


-<FIELD name="Assigned To" reportable="dimension" type="String" refname="System.AssignedTo" syncnamechanges="true">

<ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE/>

<VALIDUSER group="[project]\Scrum Team"/>

</FIELD>

<FIELD name="Work Item Type" reportable="dimension" type="String" refname="System.WorkItemType"/>

<FIELD name="Created Date" reportable="dimension" type="DateTime" refname="System.CreatedDate"/>

<FIELD name="Created By" reportable="dimension" type="String" refname="System.CreatedBy" syncnamechanges="true"/>

<FIELD name="Description" type="HTML" refname="System.Description"/>

<FIELD name="History" type="History" refname="System.History"/>

<FIELD name="Related Link Count" type="Integer" refname="System.RelatedLinkCount"/>

<FIELD name="Tags" type="PlainText" refname="System.Tags"/>

<FIELD name="Board Column" reportable="dimension" type="String" refname="System.BoardColumn"/>

<FIELD name="Board Column Done" reportable="dimension" type="Boolean" refname="System.BoardColumnDone"/>

<FIELD name="Board Lane" reportable="dimension" type="String" refname="System.BoardLane"/>


-<FIELD name="Integration Build" reportable="dimension" type="String" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild">


-<SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true">

<LISTITEM value="<None>"/>

</SUGGESTEDVALUES>


-<SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">

<GLOBALLIST name="Builds - Software"/>

</SUGGESTEDVALUES>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Description HTML" type="HTML" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.DescriptionHtml">

<DEFAULT value="The User Story must include: A Role, the Requirement and a Justification for the requirement. EXAMPLE USER STORY: As an [Electrical Lead], I want [to be able to navigate to the Results Analyser from a web browser], so that [I can analyse test results]." from="value"/>

</FIELD>

<FIELD name="Backlog Priority" reportable="detail" type="Double" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority"/>


-<FIELD name="Effort" reportable="measure" type="Double" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" formula="sum">


-<ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">

<LISTITEM value="1"/>

<LISTITEM value="13"/>

<LISTITEM value="2"/>

<LISTITEM value="3"/>

<LISTITEM value="5"/>

<LISTITEM value="8"/>

</ALLOWEDVALUES>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Business Value" reportable="measure" type="Integer" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue" formula="sum">


-<ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">

<LISTITEM value="1"/>

<LISTITEM value="2"/>

<LISTITEM value="3"/>

<LISTITEM value="4"/>

<LISTITEM value="5"/>

</ALLOWEDVALUES>

<DEFAULT value="3" from="value"/>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Detailed Requirement" type="HTML" refname="Custom.DetailedRequirement">

<HELPTEXT>Detailed Business Requirement</HELPTEXT>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Department" type="String" refname="Custom.Department">

<HELPTEXT>Department</HELPTEXT>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Office" type="String" refname="Custom.Office">

<HELPTEXT>Stakeholder's Office</HELPTEXT>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Telephone Number" type="String" refname="Custom.Telephone">

<HELPTEXT>Telephone Number</HELPTEXT>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Email Address" type="String" refname="Custom.Email">

<HELPTEXT>Stakeholder's email address</HELPTEXT>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Acceptance Test" type="HTML" refname="Custom.AcceptanceTest">

<HELPTEXT>Acceptance Test</HELPTEXT>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Stakeholder" type="String" refname="Custom.StakeholderName">

<HELPTEXT>Stakeholder Name</HELPTEXT>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="WorkItem Notes" type="HTML" refname="Custom.WINotes">

<HELPTEXT>Work Item Notes</HELPTEXT>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Dependancy" type="String" refname="Custom.Dependancy">

<HELPTEXT>Story is dependant on another story</HELPTEXT>


-<ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">

<LISTITEM value="No"/>

<LISTITEM value="Yes"/>

</ALLOWEDVALUES>

<DEFAULT value="No" from="value"/>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Relates" type="String" refname="Custom.Relates">

<HELPTEXT>Story relates to another story</HELPTEXT>


-<ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">

<LISTITEM value="No"/>

<LISTITEM value="Yes"/>

</ALLOWEDVALUES>

<DEFAULT value="No" from="value"/>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Support" type="String" refname="Custom.Support">

<HELPTEXT>Related to a Support Ticket</HELPTEXT>


-<ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">

<LISTITEM value="No"/>

<LISTITEM value="Yes"/>

</ALLOWEDVALUES>

<DEFAULT value="No" from="value"/>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Rank" reportable="detail" type="Integer" refname="Custom.Rank">

<HELPTEXT>Delivery Order</HELPTEXT>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Planned Sprint" type="String" refname="Custom.PlannedSprint">


-<ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">

<LISTITEM value="Sprint 1"/>

<LISTITEM value="Sprint 2"/>

<LISTITEM value="Sprint 3"/>

</ALLOWEDVALUES>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD name="Planned Release" type="String" refname="Custom.PlannedRelease">


-<ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">

<LISTITEM value="Rel 1"/>

<LISTITEM value="Rel 2"/>

<LISTITEM value="Rel 3"/>

<LISTITEM value="Rel 4"/>

<LISTITEM value="Rel 5"/>

<LISTITEM value="Rel 6"/>

<LISTITEM value="Rel 7"/>

<LISTITEM value="Rel 8"/>

<LISTITEM value="Rel 9"/>

</ALLOWEDVALUES>

</FIELD>

<FIELD name="Version" type="String" refname="Custom.Version"/>

</FIELDS>


-<WORKFLOW>


-<STATES>


-<STATE value="Accepted">


-<FIELDS>


-<FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue">

<READONLY/>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort">

<READONLY/>

</FIELD>

</FIELDS>

</STATE>

<STATE value="Deleted"/>

<STATE value="In Analysis"/>

<STATE value="In Development"/>

<STATE value="In test"/>

<STATE value="New"/>

<STATE value="Pending Approval"/>

<STATE value="Ready For Analysis"/>

<STATE value="Ready for Development"/>

<STATE value="Ready for Signoff"/>

<STATE value="Ready For Test"/>

<STATE value="Test Failed"/>

</STATES>


-<TRANSITIONS>


-<TRANSITION from="Ready for Development" for="[project]\Scrum Team" to="In Development">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Backlog Item: Assigned"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="In Development" for="[project]\Scrum Team" to="Ready For Test">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Backlog Item: Development Completed"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="Ready For Test" for="[project]\Scrum Team" to="In test">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Backlog Item: In Test"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="In test" for="[project]\Scrum Team" to="Ready for Signoff">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Backlog Item: QA Tests Completed"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="Ready for Signoff" for="[project]\Scrum Master" to="Accepted">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Backlog Item: Stakeholder Accepted"/>

</REASONS>


-<FIELDS>


-<FIELD refname="Custom.Version">

<REQUIRED for="[global]\Project Collection Valid Users"/>

</FIELD>

</FIELDS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="In test" to="In Development">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Backlog Item - Development Issues Found"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="In test" for="[project]\Scrum Team" to="Test Failed">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Backlog Item: Failed Quality Assurance"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="Test Failed" for="[project]\Scrum Team" to="In Development">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Backlog Item: In Re-test"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="" for="[project]\Scrum Team" to="New">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="New backlog item"/>

<REASON value="Build Failure"/>

</REASONS>


-<FIELDS>


-<FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.DescriptionHtml">

<DEFAULT value="As a &lt;type of user&gt; I want &lt;some goal&gt; so that &lt;some reason&gt;" from="value"/>

</FIELD>


-<FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority">

<DEFAULT value="3" from="value"/>

</FIELD>

</FIELDS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="In Analysis" for="[project]\Product Owner" to="New">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Backlog Item: Out of Scope"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="Ready for Development" for="[project]\Scrum Master" to="New">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Backlog Item: Out of Scope"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="New" for="[project]\Scrum Team" to="Deleted">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Backlog Item: Obsolete"/>

<REASON value="Backlog Item: Created in Error"/>

<REASON value="Backlog Item: Duplicated"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="New" to="In Analysis">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="-"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="In Analysis" to="Ready for Development">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Analysis Complete"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="Deleted" to="New">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Deleted in error"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="Ready for Signoff" to="Test Failed">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Failed Regression or UAT"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>


-<TRANSITION from="Ready for Signoff" to="In Analysis">


-<REASONS>

<DEFAULTREASON value="Customer Amendment"/>

</REASONS>

</TRANSITION>

</TRANSITIONS>

</WORKFLOW>


-<FORM>


-<Layout>


-<Group>


-<Column PercentWidth="100">

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="&Title:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="System.Title"/>

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="&Sprint:" Type="WorkItemClassificationControl" FieldName="System.IterationPath"/>

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="Feature:" Type="WorkItemClassificationControl" FieldName="System.AreaPath"/>

</Column>

</Group>


-<Group>


-<Column PercentWidth="50">


-<Group Label="Status">


-<Column PercentWidth="100">

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="Assi&gned To:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="System.AssignedTo"/>

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="&State:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="System.State"/>

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="Reason:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="System.Reason"/>

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="In Version:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.Version"/>

</Column>

</Group>

</Column>


-<Column PercentWidth="50">


-<Group Label="Details">


-<Column PercentWidth="100">

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="Business Value:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue"/>

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="Story Points:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort"/>

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="Backlog Priority:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority"/>

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="Rank:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.Rank"/>

</Column>

</Group>

</Column>

</Group>


-<Group Label="">


-<Column PercentWidth="20">

<Control LabelPosition="Top" Label="Dependant User Story?" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.Dependancy"/>

</Column>


-<Column PercentWidth="20">

<Control LabelPosition="Top" Label="Related User Story?" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.Relates"/>

</Column>


-<Column PercentWidth="20">

<Control LabelPosition="Top" Label="Related Support Ticket?" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.Support"/>

</Column>

</Group>


-<Group Label="">


-<Column PercentWidth="50">


-<TabGroup>


-<Tab Label="User Story">

<Control LabelPosition="Top" Label="" Type="HtmlFieldControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.DescriptionHtml"/>

</Tab>


-<Tab Label="Detailed Requirement">

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="" Type="HtmlFieldControl" FieldName="Custom.DetailedRequirement" MinimumSize="(0,600)"/>

</Tab>


-<Tab Label="Acceptance Criteria">

<Control LabelPosition="Top" Label="" Type="HtmlFieldControl" FieldName="Custom.AcceptanceTest" MinimumSize="(0,600)"/>

</Tab>


-<Tab Label="Storyboards">


-<Control LabelPosition="Top" Type="LinksControl" Name="StoryboardsControl">


-<LinksControlOptions>


-<LinkColumns>

<LinkColumn RefName="System.Title"/>

<LinkColumn LinkAttribute="System.Links.Comment"/>

</LinkColumns>

<WorkItemLinkFilters FilterType="excludeAll"/>


-<ExternalLinkFilters FilterType="include">

<Filter LinkType="Storyboard"/>

</ExternalLinkFilters>

</LinksControlOptions>

</Control>

</Tab>

</TabGroup>

</Column>


-<Column PercentWidth="50">


-<TabGroup>


-<Tab Label="Tasks">


-<Control LabelPosition="Top" Type="LinksControl" Name="Task">


-<LinksControlOptions>


-<LinkColumns>

<LinkColumn RefName="System.Id"/>

<LinkColumn RefName="System.Title"/>

<LinkColumn RefName="System.AssignedTo"/>

<LinkColumn RefName="System.State"/>

</LinkColumns>


-<WorkItemLinkFilters FilterType="include">

<Filter LinkType="System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy" FilterOn="forwardname"/>

</WorkItemLinkFilters>

<ExternalLinkFilters FilterType="excludeAll"/>


-<WorkItemTypeFilters FilterType="include" Scope="project">

<Filter WorkItemType="Sprint Backlog Task"/>

</WorkItemTypeFilters>

</LinksControlOptions>

</Control>

</Tab>


-<Tab Label="Links">


-<Control LabelPosition="Top" Label="" Type="LinksControl" Name="GeneralLinks">


-<LinksControlOptions>


-<LinkColumns>

<LinkColumn RefName="System.Id"/>

<LinkColumn RefName="System.Title"/>

<LinkColumn RefName="System.AssignedTo"/>

<LinkColumn RefName="System.State"/>

<LinkColumn LinkAttribute="System.Links.Comment"/>

</LinkColumns>

<WorkItemLinkFilters FilterType="includeAll"/>

<ExternalLinkFilters FilterType="includeAll"/>

<WorkItemTypeFilters FilterType="includeAll"/>

</LinksControlOptions>

</Control>

</Tab>


-<Tab Label="Attachments">

<Control LabelPosition="Top" Label="" Type="AttachmentsControl"/>

</Tab>


-<Tab Label="Stakeholder Information">


-<Group Label="Contact Information">


-<Column PercentWidth="100">

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="Name:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.StakeholderName"/>

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="Department:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.Department"/>

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="Office:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.Office"/>

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="Telephone:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.Telephone"/>

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="Email Address:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.Email"/>

</Column>

</Group>


-<Group Label="Additional Information">


-<Column PercentWidth="100">

<Control LabelPosition="Left" Label="Notes:" Type="HtmlFieldControl" FieldName="Custom.WINotes"/>

</Column>

</Group>

</Tab>


-<Tab Label="History">

<Control LabelPosition="Top" Label="" Type="WorkItemLogControl" FieldName="System.History" Dock="Fill"/>

</Tab>

</TabGroup>

</Column>

</Group>


-<Group>


-<Column PercentWidth="10">

<Control LabelPosition="Top" Label="Planned Release:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.PlannedRelease"/>

</Column>


-<Column PercentWidth="10">

<Control LabelPosition="Top" Label="Planned Sprint:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.PlannedSprint"/>

</Column>

</Group>

</Layout>

</FORM>

</WORKITEMTYPE>

</witd:WITD>
```

Comment: Can you share the work item definition for one of the impacted workitems? And can you run `witadmin listfields /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection` and post the output?

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, your title field is not using the default system.Title reference, but using System.AssignedTo reference. You need to check your work item type definition and correct this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see last edit - I have uploaded system.title for PBI work item.

Comment: Check the Layout tab as the screenshot I posted.

Comment: Uploaded... see link.

Comment: Please share the work item definition for one of the impacted workitems as @ jessehouwing mentioned in comment.

Comment: Please see edit - I have also confirmed the title fields still are present within SQL using: 
Select * from tbl_WorkItemCustomLatest where Id = ‘<PBI Id>’

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but it might help someone in the future.

I had this issue while upgrading from TFS 2013 to TFS 2017. The issue was due to some projects having a WIT with these lines in them:

```
<FIELD refname="System.Title">
<WHEN field="System.WorkItemType" value="Test Case">
  <VALIDUSER for="{cliente_user_group}" />
</WHEN>
</FIELD>
```

With this, after the upgrade, we were getting this setting on the System.Title collection field:

```
>witadmin listfields /collection:{collection} /n:System.Title

...
Synchronizes Identity Name Changes: True
```

This flag can't be changed on System.Title so we had to go back to TFS 2013 to change the problematic WIT.

After removing those lines from the WITD on the affected projects and re-upgrading the issue no longer happened.